# Add 2 text fields in a single param in xml

Tags: xml, xsd

I created a new text field in xml using parameters, for example,

```
<param name="address" 
       type="text" 
       mandatory="" 
       label="Address" 
       size="100"/>
```

Similarly, i need to create 2 text fields in the same param. Is any possible way to create 2 text fields in a single param?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Whether you can create two text fields with a single `param` element depends entirely on the design decisions made by the creators of the XML vocabulary you are using.  It's not an XML or schema-language question; it's entirely a question about the unidentified vocabulary you are using.

If you can identify that vocabulary, there may be someone reading Stack Overflow who can answer your question; if you really want a fully generic answer, it is 'yes, of course there is a possible way - the designers of your language just need to specify that as the semantics of a particular markup construct'.